# Does Django queryset values_list return a list object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a Django app where users post photos, and other leave comments under the photos.

When a comment is left, I need to notify:

1. Everyone else who wrote in this thread
2. The owner of the photo, in case they're not included in (1)

For (1), I do:

```
#I slice by 25 because I arbitrarily deem anyone beyond that irrelevant. 
all_commenter_ids = PhotoComment.objects.filter(which_photo=which_photo).order_by('-id').values_list('submitted_by', flat=True)[:25]
```

Next, for (2), I try:

```
all_relevant_ids = all_commenter_ids.append(which_photo.owner_id)
all_relevant_ids = list(set(all_relevant_ids))
```

I end up with an error:

> 'ValuesListQuerySet' object has no attribute 'append'

I find this strange, because I'm extracting a **values_list**.

Isn't that a list object, and in that case, shouldn't the attribute `append` work in this scenario? Please explain what's wrong, and suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `values_list` method returns a `ValuesListQuerySet`. This means it has the advantages of a queryset. For example it is lazy, so you only fetch the first 25 elements from the database when you slice it.

To convert it to a list, use `list()`.

```
all_commenter_ids = PhotoComment.objects.filter(which_photo=which_photo).order_by('-id').values_list('submitted_by', flat=True)[:25]
all_commenter_ids = list(all_commenter_ids)
```

You might be able to start the queryset from your `User` model instead of using `values_list`. You haven't shown your models, so the following code is a guess:

```
from django.db.models import Q

commenters = User.objects.filter(Q(id=which_photo.owner_id)|Q(photocomment=which_photo))
```

Comment: Hmm I get `'NoneType' object is not iterable` on the line `all_relevant_ids = list(set(all_relevant_ids))` the moment I post the first comment after applying your fix. I'll need to look deeper into this.

Comment: Note that the `append` method returns `None`. You want simply `all_commenter_ids.append(which_photo.owner_id)` - don't assign the result to `all_relevant_ids`.

Comment: as an aside, should I enclude the values_list slice I'm taking in `set` as well, since some ids may be repeated? Re: the User objects route, photocomment isn't part of the User, hence can't do that. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Whether you slice or not is up to you. Since you are calling `set()` on the result, you might end up with fewer than 25 entries in your final list. If you need 25 items, then you might need to convert to a set, then back to a list, then slice. However that will fetch all the ids from the database, which could be slow. I'm not sure how you could get the first 25 unique ids using the ORM.

Comment: This seems like poorly named method to me, not surprising there's so much confusion.