# AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: django, django-models

Somewhere in my code it says

```
publisher.publisherperson_set.remove(email__in=pp_remove_set)
```

Upon executing this, I got

> AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'remove'

And indeed: I looked at `dir(publisher.publisherperson_set)` and it had plenty of operations (including `add`), but not `remove`.

Under which circumstances is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Cannot be `null`

The [documentation for `RelatedManager.remove()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/) says

> For `ForeignKey` objects, this method only exists if `null=True`. 
>   If the related field can’t be set to `None` (`NULL`), then 
>   an object can’t be removed from a relation without being added to another.

Obvious, once you think about it.
What I really intended to do was this:

```
publisher.publisherperson_set.filter(email__in=pp_remove_set).delete()
```

Answer (score 14):

Just posting this since I got here from a related search 
`AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'delete'`

What I was looking for was:

```
thing.stuff_set.all().delete()
```

note: still learning django, but i'm assuming any queryset operations `filter`, `all`, `order_by`, `exclude`, `annotate`, etc

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.ordered

can be used. Although I'm not sure at the moment what sort of nuance there is in regards to the queryset list return from `all()` and the `stuff_set`:

- [Does Django queryset values_list return a list object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140426/does-django-queryset-values-list-return-a-list-object#37140717)