# how to find if string is in a result of a query set in Django

Tags: django

I have the following object result from query set on a model as follow:

```
ddd = Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(
    category_name__category_name__iexact=dd
).values_list('sub_category_name', flat=True)
```

the query set I obtained:

```
<QuerySet ['car', 'spare parts', 'truck', 'motor cycle']>
```

then tried:

```
print(ddd.values('sub_category_name'))
```

I obtained the following result:

```
<QuerySet [
    <Post_Sub_Category: car>,
    <Post_Sub_Category: spare parts>,
    <Post_Sub_Category: truck>,
    <Post_Sub_Category: motor cycle>
]
```

How to access the values only and make list of them as string:

```
['car','spare parts','truck','motor cycle'].
```

the first query set seems that it gave me what I want. However, When I use following if statement. it does not executed:

```
if 'car' in ddd:
    #  do some thing
```

as you can see `car` should be in the list. so, I could not understand why the if statement has not been executed.

any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to index that. The values list actually looks like it returns a list. Can you try:

```
try: 
    ddd = ddd[0]
except IndexError: 
    # Catch index error
    pass 

if 'car' in ddd:
    #  do some thing
```

If that doesn't work, try explicitly converting your QuerySetList to a regular ole list, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140426/does-django-queryset-values-list-return-a-list-object), like this:

```
ddd = list(ddd)
```

Also, this looks a little strange to me: `category_name__category_name__iexact=dd`. Posting your corresponding models would be helpful.

Comment: The suggested answer in the link you provided me with does the work. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140426/does-django-queryset-values-list-return-a-list-object)

Comment: The link is broken? Or using `list` on your QuerySet didn't work?